# Create object with correct ID in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm learning rails via writing some simple application and in that app I have two types of objects: Tasks and Projects.Sense is that all those objects can be created by user,user must be able to manipulate them and so on.Each task belongs_to project and project has_many tasks.But when I create new project - it already has all tasks from all another projects,so it looks like: 
[image]

This '123' task was created by simply adding task to 'Project' but same task still appear in 'Another project'.How can I fix this bug and make my task unique?I think something must be added to task or projects model but I don't know what should I add.

Here are corresponding  controllers:
tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to home_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to home_url }
        format.json { render :home_url, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to home_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:deadline, :name, :project_id)
end
end
```

projects_controller.rb

```
   class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /projects
  # GET /projects.json
  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /projects
  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to home_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to home_url }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :home_url }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  # DELETE /projects/1.json
  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to home_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

And the corresponding views:
for tasks

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <div  class="row task">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-1 checkbox">
         <%= check_box_tag 'accept' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 taskbody">
        <%= task.name %>
      </div>
    <div class="mini-glyph">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <%= link_to edit_task_path(task) do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        <span><%= link_to " ", task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class:"glyphicon glyphicon-trash" %></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And for projects:

```
<div class="container">
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <div  class="projectblock">
    <div class="row project-bar">
      <div class="col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
        </div>
        <div  class="col-xs-9 prname">
          <%= project.name %></td>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <%= link_to edit_project_path(project) do %>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <span><%= link_to " ", project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class:"glyphicon glyphicon-trash" %></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="row add-task-bar">
        <div class="input-bar col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus col-xs-1 left_plus" ></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10" >
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Start typing here to create a task...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><%= link_to 'Add task', new_task_path %></button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 taskbody">
<% project.tasks.each do |task| %>
  <%= @task.name %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
    <% end %>
</div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
      <div class="todo-btn col-xs-4">
        <a href="projects/new" class="btn">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            Add TODO list
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know I'm asking this for the second time,but the last question wasn't answered fully because of my mistake - I simply can't understand exactly where should I insert that "Task.where(project_id: project_id) "
So I'm forced to ask for an advice again

Project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be here:

```
<%= render :template => 'tasks/index' %>
```

You don't show your code, but basically you are rendering all your tasks, from a index which I imagine is just calling all tasks.

What you want to do is replace this with something like:

```
<% project.tasks.each do |task| %>
  <%= task.name %> <%= task.whatever_else_xx %>
<% end %>
```

I've not put them into a format, but you can just wrap the html as required, and I've not used a partial which you might want to do, and I've assumed that project is what your project object is populated as, and it contains has_many :tasks, but you should get the idea.

You don't actually need to do Tasks.where, rails active record will take care of it for you, however I have noticed this line might be a bit problematic:

```
params.require(:task).permit(:deadline, :name)
```

When you create a task, it needs to set the project_id column that your database should have, if you've used migration - this sets the parent project for a given task.

```
params.require(:task).permit(:deadline, :name, :project_id)
```

and you need to make sure that this is sent up in the form as a hidden field.. You can manually check that the above code is working, by manually adding the project_id that you need to the task row, but for new tasks the id should be sent up.

Comment: More looking for class Project < ActiveRecord has_many: tasks end ?

Comment: I've added my models,but (sorry if I'm to annoying) did you mean that I can leave all those "where" and leave controller as is,just by changing the corresponding view?

Comment: And sorry again for that broken comment

Comment: Don't worry! You might want to do some clean up, but the snippet I provided should work by just replacing in the view. Let me know, by comment if not!

Comment: TY, I'll try in a couple of minutes and will certainly inform you)

Comment: Well,I've replaced my code with your snippet and now page doesn't show any tasks at all(

Comment: OK, and I just spotted something else which probably is why :) I've already edited my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108046/discussion-between-mikhah-and-tim).

Comment: Big thanks to Tim for all that time he'd spent on me (and maybe will spend))